# Transponer una columna con la referencia de una fecha - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo un dataframe donde necesito dividir los datos de sensóren 3 columnas diferentes (una por cada tipo de dato de sensórica), y deben coincidir por la fecha.

La siguiente imagen es como tengo el df actualmente:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente imagen es una muestra del resultado del df que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un enlace con el dataframe original:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5X1lK8yYkYrS9-2myEa_-njtsdt57cN/view?usp=sharing

He intentado trasponer, pero no tengo muy claro como hacerlo.

```
df = df.pivot(index='fechaValor', columns='sensorica', values='Valor')
```

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, hay varias formas de hacerlo:

**Nota:** El URL que pusiste parece que no funciona, utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` genérico en un archivo "sample2.csv"

```
    id      sensorica       fechaValor          Valor
0   ADN-515 Temperatura     19/05/2022 22:02    233.081
1   ADN-515 Humedad         19/05/2022 22:02    658.732
2   ADN-515 Acelerómetro    19/05/2022 22:02    329.476
3   ADN-515 Temperatura     19/05/2022 22:12    229.924
4   ADN-515 Humedad         19/05/2022 22:12    680.006
5   ADN-515 Acelerómetro    19/05/2022 22:12    10.085
```

### Utilizando [`pandas.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df1 = df.pivot(index=['id', 'fechaValor'], columns='sensorica', values='Valor').reset_index()
df1.columns.name = '' #Esto para eliminar el nombre de las columnas que era "sensorica"
print(df1)
```

Al imprimir `df1` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    id      fechaValor          Acelerómetro    Humedad Temperatura
0   ADN-515 19/05/2022 22:02    329.476         658.732 233.081
1   ADN-515 19/05/2022 22:12    10.085          680.006 229.924
```

### Utilizando [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

Sería exactamente igual pero utilizando otra función:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'fechaValor'], columns='sensorica', values='Valor').reset_index()
df1.columns.name = ''
print(df1)
```

### Utilizando [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df1 = pd.crosstab(index=[df['id'], df['fechaValor']], columns=df['sensorica'], colnames=[None], values = df['Valor'], aggfunc=lambda x: x).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

### Utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'fechaValor', 'sensorica']).agg({'Valor': lambda x: x}).unstack('sensorica').reset_index()
df1.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
df1.columns = ['id', 'fechaValor', 'Acelerómetro', 'Humedad', 'Temperatura']
print(df1)
```

Una desventaja de este método es que al utilizar groupby se crean multiples niveles de columnas por lo que tenemos que utilizar `reset_index` del `dataframe` transpuesto (Con [`pandas.DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html?highlight=pandas%20dataframe%20t#pandas.DataFrame.T)) y luego transponerlo otra vez, al final debemos dar nombre a cada columna.

### Nota adicional

Te recomiendo probar con todos los métodos (Hay más formas de hacerlo pero la respuesta quedaría muy grande) y ejecutarlos línea por línea, también lee la documentación de cada uno para ver la diferencia, ventajas y/o desventajas.

**Para todos los ejemplos el resultado es el mismo que el primer ejemplo pero los omití para hacer más breve la respuesta.**

Comment: hola @heytalepazguato muchas gracias por toda la info! No me esperaba tantas funcionalidades disponibles! Iré probando una a una y documentándome como dices!